# Why does Visual Studio 2019 automatically setup git source control?

Tags: angular, git, visual-studio-2019, source-control-explorer

I set up a new Angular app with "ng new todo".   Then I opened Visual Studio 2019.  I selected open folder and opened the folder of the Angular app.  I noticed the little green + icons next to all the files right away.  Visual Studio 2019 seems to have automatically setup source control just by opening the folder in git in a local repository.  Why did it do that?  I don't want VS 2019 doing that automatically.  I want to control how, when and where I set up my source control and repositories.  Is there a way to unhook that and just kill the repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't Visual Studio, it's Angular. The `ng new` command will create a new git repository. Visual Studio will show source-control annotations on Solution Explorer items if it detects a git repo.

Use `ng new --skip-git` (or `--skipGit=true`) to prevent it from creating a new Git repo with `ng new`.

Oddly, the integration with git isn't explicitly mentioned in the documentation for `ng new` 
 https://angular.io/cli/new ) but the page does mention the command-line flags regarding git.

Comment: I didn't realize that.  That makes sense.